How can we make the BottomSheet modal not cover the bottom navigation bar
I have a bottomSheet modal which I am calling from BottomNavigationBar. I still want to be able to access the bottom navigation bar even when the  modal is open . I tried using useRootNavigator: true, but I still can not access the bottom navigation bar.
I am calling the modal as follows:
void _onItemTapped(int index) async {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });

    if (index == 4) {
      if (_controller.isCompleted) {
        _controller.reverse();
      } else {
        _controller.forward();
        await showModalBottomSheet(
          useRootNavigator: true,
          context: context,
          isScrollControlled: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          builder: (context) => DraggableScrollableSheet(
            initialChildSize:
                0.9, 
            maxChildSize:
                0.9, 
            minChildSize: 0.3, // Minimum height of the modal.
            builder: (_, controller) => ListView(
              controller: controller,
              children: [
                MoreOptionsModal(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
        _controller.reverse();
      }
    } else {
      _controller.reverse();
    }
  }

...
 body: SafeArea(child: _screens.elementAt(_selectedIndex).body!),
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: _buildBottomNavItems(),
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: 
          _onItemTapped
        ,)

I believe this is related to the discussion here https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/140812 which was unfortunately closed without solving the problem.

As the showModalBottomSheet function's documentation mentions, it is an alternative to a menu or a dialog, which prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the app while it's open.
In your case, I believe what you need is ScaffoldState.showBottomSheet. This method shows a Material Design bottom sheet in the nearest Scaffold, allowing the bottom navigation bar to remain accessible.
Here is an example demonstrating how to achieve the desired behavior:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: ExampleApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class ExampleApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExampleApp> createState() => _ExampleAppState();
}

class _ExampleAppState extends State<ExampleApp> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Example App'),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            label: 'Home',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.business),
            label: 'Business',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.school),
            label: 'School',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (index) {
          setState(() => _currentIndex = index);

          _scaffoldKey.currentState?.showBottomSheet(
            showDragHandle: true,
            (_) => SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Bottom Sheet Index: $_currentIndex'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Page Index: $_currentIndex'),
      ),
    );
  }
}


